# Error while handling csv files with more than 1000 rows using pandas library in python script to merge csv files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

when the dataset is small this works fine. But if the data set is large, it considers the whole columns as one single column in the output CSV file. so when we use .drop() function to delete a column with a column name,it shows "not found in axis"

the code I used is given below

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'path to csv files'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []  #list to store csv

for filename in all_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
        li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
frame=frame.drop(columns=['column_name'])
frame.to_csv('/path to save final csv/new_file.csv')
print(frame)
```

Comment: can you help @Gaurav Singh

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'path to csv files'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []  #list to store csv

for filename in all_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
        li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
frame.drop(columns=['column_name'],axis=1,inplace=True)
frame.to_csv('/path to save final csv/new_file.csv')
print(frame)
```